# Select checkbox dropdown inside select checkbox dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, select-options

I want to create a Select checkbox list under the Select Checkbox dropdown again. What do I have to do?

Sample i need

```
☑ C 1 : name

       ☐ C 1.1 : name

       ☑ C 1.2 : name

☐ C2 : name

☐ C3 : name
```

My code

form views

```
     <label>Standard List</label>
            <select type="button"id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control" >
            <option class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
            <option value="CakePHP">CakePHP</option>
            <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
            <option value="YII">YII</option>
            <option value="Zend">Zend</option>
            <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
            <option value="Phalcon">Phalcon</option>
            <option value="Slim">Slim</option>
            </select>
```

Js :

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#framework').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Choose...',
     enableFiltering: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
   buttonWidth:'400px'
   });
  });
```

Comment: Can you create snippet?

Comment: Noooooo i can't

Comment: Yes you can. I mean if you want to help us help you. Also, be more precise on what you want to achieve, it's unclear.

Comment: Why you can't??

Comment: https://codepen.io/wongsatron-dongnin/pen/RwrawWo   Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using JQuery:
(Just DOM)

HTML:

```html
<!--------C1------------>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
<label>C 1</label><br>
<div id="c1-hidden" style="display:none">
    &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
    <label>C 1.1</label><br>
     &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
<label>C 1.2</label>
</div>

<!--------C2------------->
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" onclick="check()">
<label>C 2</label><br>
<div id="c2-hidden" style="display:none">
    &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
    <label>C 2.1</label><br>
     &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
<label>C 2.2</label>
</div>

<!--------C3------------->
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" onclick="check()">
<label>C 3</label>
<div id="c3-hidden" style="display:none">
    &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
    <label>C 3.1</label><br>
     &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="check()">
<label>C 3.2</label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
<script>
var checkboxes = ["c1","c2","c3"];
function check(){
    checkboxes.forEach(item=>{
        if(document.getElementById(item).checked==true){
            document.getElementById(item+"-hidden").style.display = "block";
        }else{
document.getElementById(item+"-hidden").style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I already can help. But I want it to be searchable as well Can we change to the select option check box?

Comment: select option doesn't make something searchable.

Comment: There are some more libraries that are involved with that codepen,

Comment: all of the     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.3/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?

etc etc ......

Comment: So what do I have to do to make it searchable? Like I sent in codepen

Comment: You will need to write a lot more javascript code, or use some other libraries.

Why do you need the thing to be searchable anyways?

Unless you are making a large database of things you want people to be able to search and as well as select(Like stackoverflow's questions). Then you don't need "Search".

You definately don't need "Search" for a 10 element dropdown.

Comment: es, I need to do it because it is large database.

Comment: Try use some library like this one : https://fusejs.io/
But you will still need to write a lot more of javascript.

Comment: And that should be a separate question on stack over flow :) Best of Luck hope you make it work in the end.

Comment: No problems :))